# Using AVFoundation, can I capture the last 5 seconds when the user presses the button

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Consider the following scenario:

A user loads up an app with a camera and a custom button as its main view.
On viewDidLoad for the relevant view controller I'm starting an AVSession (so its now running)
The moment the user taps the custom button I would like to capture the 5 seconds of video before the user pressed that button. Of course this could be less than 5 seconds.

How would I go about implementing this? I've been looking at AVFoundation for a day or so now, trying to learn the basic concepts and its slowly making sense to me, and I'm using the AVCam project from Apple at the moment, which has been very helpful.

At this stage pointers to the classes I should be looking at, concept explanations or code snippets would be most welcome.

Thank you

EDIT: A bit more info about what I'm trying to achieve, basically when I call startRunning on my AVSession, it will be updating a preview layer I have in the app, so the user can see what they'll be filming. I'd also like that data to stream to a buffer/file that can be saved when the button is tapped.

Thanks

Comment: Stefan answer is correct. The only option you have is to continuously record your movie and save it to your apps temp dir. When user presses down on your button you need to trim that video to its last 5 seconds. Since you have no idea how long it will take the user to press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about continuously recording to a file, and then copying the last 5 seconds from that file when the button is pressed?

Buffering video in memory will never work, and as far as I know you cannot get hardware compression without saving to a file.

Comment: I'd love to see an actual implementation of this BTW, it's a really interesting use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to look into recording into a temp directory. If I ever manage to implement it I'll try to update this post.

Comment: yesterday I also got this crazy idea about recording raw to a in memory buffer, and then using an asset writer to compress and save to disk. that might allow full control over buffers and stuff, but memory usage will likely be an issue on 4/4s.